# Making SVG Responsive in React

Tags: d3.js, svg, reactjs, data-visualization, react-d3

I am working on a responsive utility component, to make a few D3 components responsive in react. However I deep SVG knowledge escapes me. I have based my responsive utility on [this issue on github](https://gist.github.com/f15gdsy/3a2c230b061bd11a7be4). However it isn't quite working, All it does is render the a chart, but not at the `width` or `height` passed in but rather at a really small width and height. It also doesn't resize.

```js
import React from 'react';

class Responsive extends React.Component{
    constructor () {
      super();
      this.state = {
        size: {
          w: 0,
          h: 0
        }
      }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.fitToParentSize.bind(this));
        this.fitToParentSize();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps () {
        this.fitToParentSize();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.fitToParentSize.bind(this));
    }

    fitToParentSize () {
        let elem = this.findDOMNode(this);
        let w = elem.parentNode.offsetWidth;
        let h = elem.parentNode.offsetHeight;
        let currentSize = this.state.size;

        if (w !== currentSize.w || h !== currentSize.h) {
            this.setState({
                size: {
                    w: w,
                    h: h
                }
            });
        }
    }

    render () {

        let {width, height} = this.props;

        width = this.state.size.w || 100;
        height = this.state.size.h || 100;

        var Charts = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { width, height});

        return Charts;
    }
};

export default Responsive;
```

```js
Responsive width={400} height={500}>
  <XYAxis data={data3Check}
          xDataKey='x'
          yDataKey='y'
          grid={true}
          gridLines={'solid'}>
    <AreaChart dataKey='a'/>
    <LineChart dataKey='l' pointColor="#ffc952" pointBorderColor='#34314c'/>
  </XYAxis>
</Responsive>
```

Comment: use a viewBox attribute to make SVG responsive.

Comment: @RobertLongson could you elaborate please?

Comment: In what way should I elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

disclaimer: I'm the author of [vx](https://vx-demo.now.sh/gallery) a low-level react+d3 library full of visualization components.

You could use [`@vx/responsive`](https://github.com/hshoff/vx/blob/master/packages/vx-responsive/) or create your own higher-order component based on [`withParentSize()`](https://github.com/hshoff/vx/blob/master/packages/vx-responsive/src/enhancers/withParentSize.js) or [`withWindowSize()`](https://github.com/hshoff/vx/blob/master/packages/vx-responsive/src/enhancers/withScreenSize.js) depending on what sizing you want to respond to (I've found most situations require `withParentSize()`).

The gist is you create a higher-order component that takes in your chart component and it attaches/removes event listeners for when the window resizes with a debounce time of `300ms` by default (you can override this with a prop) and stores the dimensions in its state. The new parent dimensions will get passed in as props to your chart as `parentWidth, parentHeight` or `screenWidth, screenHeight` and you can set your svg's width and height attributes from there or calculate your chart dimensions based on those values.

Usage:

```
// MyChart.js
import { withParentSize } from '@vx/responsive';

function MyChart({ parentWidth, parentHeight }) {
  return (
    <svg width={parentWidth} height={parentHeight}>
      {/* stuff */}
    </svg>
  );
}

export default withParentSize(MyChart);
```